# Use single buildslave to service multiple buildmasters

Tags: python, build-automation, buildbot

I have 2 buildbots and would like to share a buildslave across them. 
Both the buildbots/masters have different repos.

Is there a way to share the buildslave across the multiple buildbots?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently any way to connect a single buildslave to multiple buildmasters. You can run multiple buildslaves on a single machine without difficulty, but that wont handle limiting concurrent build between buildmasters.

There is an open [ticket](http://trac.buildbot.net/ticket/301) to support this.